# discord.py automatically sending a result on discord as a direct message

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, discord, discord.py

I'd like to know how I could make this script send the result (won or lost) on the specific user's direct message, here is a simple example of this:

```
    from discord.ext import commands
    import discord
    import os
    from random import *
    
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print('Bot Is Ready')
    
    @client.command() #The command in order to execute the script first
    async def dm(ctx):
        
        rand_num = (randint(1, 3))
        win_num = 1
        
        if rand_num == win_num:
            print("number was:", rand_num)
            print("won")
            @client.event
            async def on_win():
                dmessage.send.user("You won!") #Send the won result message via direct message on discord automatically
    
        elif rand_num != win_num:
            print("number was:", rand_num)
            print("lost")
            @client.event
            async def on_lost():
                dmessage.send.user("You lost") #Send the lost result message via direct message on discord automatically
    
    client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send **prive message**(**direct message**) you can use `member.create_dm` and you can't use something like `on_win` or `on_lost`.

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    rand_num = (randint(1, 3))
    win_num = 1
    pm_channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    if win_num == rand_num:
        await pm_channel.send("You won!")
    else:
        await pm_channel.send("You lost")
```

So in this code, member when member writes `prefix + dm`, it'll check the `rand_num` and `win_num` then it'll send the result to the user.